# Windows Powershell and Command Prompt Issue on Windows 10 OS

Tags: powershell, command-line, windows-10

I have two queries that needs to be resolved.

1. How can I resize **Windows Powershell** to a considerable size in Windows 10? I have already tried using the **Properties** options and via ** Layout**. 
   But the moment I re-launch it, the window size goes to an in-proportionate size. **(Please check the image attached for this query)**

***P.S*** - I also browsed Stack-overflow and found this link - [https://superuser.com/questions/68013/how-can-i-set-the-powershell-default-window-size-in-windows-7] but wasn't able to eliminate the issue. :(

**Image - 1: [In-proportionate size of Windows Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C407m.png)**

2. Other than query #1, I also want to know - when I try to open cmd window in a particular folder, I am not able to see the option reading **open cmd window here** in the **context sensitive menu**. For quick reference, **I am also attaching one image for this query**.

**Image - 2: [No option to open Command Prompt via context-sensitive menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzwAu.png)**

**P.S: I am getting the option to open Windows Powershell in the above image**

I earnestly request the experts here to guide me on these two queries so that I can use both Windows Powershell and Command Prompt without worrying about the size of the window every time.

I look forward to some quick guidance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it in the properties on Powershell window.

[image]

After,

[image]

When you reopen Powershell, these settings will be saved. Tune `Window Position` values as well as needed.

For your 2nd issue, read on this link - https://fossbytes.com/powershell-replaces-command-prompt-windows/

> If you aren’t ready to accept this change and ditch Command Prompt,
>   you can opt out of the WIN+X change. To do this, open Settings >
>   Personalization > Taskbar. Now, turn the “Replace Command Prompt with
>   Windows PowerShell in the menu when I right-click the Start button or
>   press Windows key+X” option to “Off”.

Comment: Hello, 

I have already tried setting these via **Layout** option, but it stiil remains the same.

For the second query, I changed the option to **OFF**, but the issue still exists. It still shows **option to open Powershell rather than cmd window**

Comment: Hmm they work fine on my Windows 10 machine. Maybe your Windows installation is not able to save settings? Is it a proper machine or a VM?

Comment: Hi, 

It's a proper Dell Inspiron laptop. I am currently using Windows 10, version 1709 **(checked via Windows update window)**

Comment: Any other stack overflow user who can guide me on the same please.

Answer (score 0):

As for this...

> open cmd window here in the context sensitive

Option: 
You can just select any directory and click the Explorer search bar and type cmd or powershell or pwsh (v6 if you have it installed) and it will start in that directory; As long as you don't have directory configured in you PowerShell profile.

You can add thing to the context menu using the Registry editor

See instructions here:

Add the Command Prompt to the Windows Explorer Right-Click Menu

A hidden functionality in Windows allows you to right click on a directory, and select “Command Prompt Here” from the menu.

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu

Just as you can for PowerShell

Add PowerShell to Windows Explorer Context Menu in Windows 10

Ever since the days of Windows Vista, it was possible to use Windows Explorer’s context menu to quickly open a command prompt window to a specific location by holding the shift key and right-clicking a folder. The “Open Command Prompt Here” appeared, allowing you to open the command prompt in the folder of your choice.

https://www.petri.com/add-powershell-windows-explorer-context-menu-windows-10

BTW, you can add anything you wish to your SendTo menu as well, just by copying the short cut there, and then that too will show up in the explore context menu for use.

As far as your PowerShell Window being overly large/small. Of course the is not the default and something / someone did that. I seen that, but never had it happen to me.

Have you made a lot of customizations?
Is this only happen in your logged on session, vs other users of the system?

So, are you saying also, you cannot resize the Window using your mouse to another size?

Try this first.

Exit the console host.
Open the PowerShell_ISE
Reset the defaults there using these commands

```
$PSise.Options.RestoreDefaults()
$PSise.Options.RestoreDefaultConsoleTokenColors()
$PSise.Options.RestoreDefaultTokenColors()
$PSise.Options.RestoreDefaultXMLTokenColors()
```

Next start the console host from the ISE by clicking the console host icon in the toolbar.

Try and work the properties from there, then close and reopen the console host form the ISE to see if the settings stayed.

Then open the console host from whatever shortcut you normally use and see if the changes remained.

If that does not reposition / resize the console windows then this is Windows proper causing this. Similar to a Window being off screen that you can't get to.

Then right click an open space on the taskbar and select Cascade windows.
If that does not work use the move option from the Taskbar.

Use Shift+Tab to select the console Windows.
Shift+RightClick the taskbar icon of the Window and select move.
The close and check again.

Lastly, if you have not done a lot of customizations, you can grab the default PowerShell regkey from another user / profile and import that into your registry.

If you don't have another default logon to use, just create one, check PowerShell state and the get that regkey to use.

Last thing, I meant to add, if none of the above works and you don't want to take the RegKey route. Create a PowerShell console profile and add this code to it. This of course will run each time you start you console using your profile. Of course adjust as needed,

```
$ConsoleSettings = (Get-Host).ui.rawui
$ScreenBufferSettings = $ConsoleSettings.buffersize
$ScreenBufferSettings.height = 50
$ScreenBufferSettings.width = 120
# $ConsoleSettings.buffersize = $ScreenBufferSettings
$ScreenSizeSettings = $ConsoleSettings.windowsize
$ScreenSizeSettings.height = 50
$ScreenSizeSettings.width = 120
$ConsoleSettings.windowsize = $ScreenSizeSettings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed instructions. Will try it in a while and see if it works.. Will keep you posted about this..

Comment: No worries.  My last edit should address your issue, well, if you use profiles of course or you can just set this as a script on your desktop / taskbar to click to run as needed as well.

Comment: I am the sole user of my Dell laptop. Let me try running this script as a batch file. May be it works that ways.. Whatever be the case, I will keep you notified and if I face any issues while following your instructions, I know where to find you... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Understood. 8^}

Comment: Hi, 

Tried using this link - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/add-the-command-prompt-to-the-windows-explorer-right-click-menu

It didn't work out neither in case of using regedit, nor in case of making a .reg file and running it. 

Also, the link - https://www.petri.com/add-powershell-windows-explorer-context-menu-windows-10
doesn't solve my issue. It's about adding Powershell to Win-explorer and not about setting Powershell window size to a consistent proportion.

Comment: Also, I have made 0 customizations. I am able to resize Powershell window using a mouse..

Would like to know what is - PowerShell_ISE? I am quite new to Powershell, so not sure about this term as well. 

It would be great if you could assist me a little bit here.

Comment: **EDIT - Powershell window issue is now resolved.** It worked via **Properties >> Layout** option itself. Played with the figures a little bit and it worked. :)

Awaiting response on **Command Prompt** issue though...